# To prove that $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^x-x}{x-1-\ln x}=3$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I have to prove that the given limit
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^x-x}{x-1-\log x}=3$$
Since it is of the form $0/0$, I thought I can use L'Hôpital's rule, but I am stuck at the first step itself.

I don't know if I should apply limit on $x^x$ separately too.

Comment: To calculate $\frac{d}{dx}x^x$ use this trick

$f(x):=x^x \Leftrightarrow \ln(f(x))=x\ln(x)$ and then try derivativing both side

Comment: $\log$ looks better if you write \log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^x - x = e^{x \ln x} - x$ has derivative $x^x \cdot (\ln x + 1) - 1$, so by L'Hôpital's you end up with
$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x^x \cdot (\ln x + 1) - 1}{1 - 1/x} = \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x^{x+1} (\ln x + 1) - x}{x - 1}.$$
Applying L'Hôpital's one more time yields 
$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x^x + x^x (\ln x + 1) (x + x \ln x + 1) - 1}{1} = 2.$$
I therefore think that your claimed value of 3 is wrong; wolframlpha agrees: [see here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22Limit%22,%20%22limitfunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22(x%5Ex%20-%20x)%2F(x-1-lnx)%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22Limit%22,%20%22limit%22%7D%20-%3E%221%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22FVarOpt%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%7B%22Limit%22,%20%22limitvariable%22%7D%7D&rawformassumption=%7B%22C%22,%20%22limit%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D).

Answer (score 1):

L'Hopital rule can be applied more than once

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^x-x}{x-1-\log x}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^x (\log x +1)-1}{1-\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x^x \left(\frac{1}{x}+(\log x+1)^2\right)}{\frac{1}{x^2}}=$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 1} x^{x+1} \left(x+1+x \log ^2 x+2 x \log x\right)=2$$

Answer (score 1):

Put $x=1+h$ so that $h\to 0$. Then the given expression can be written as $$(1+h)\cdot\frac{(1+h)^{h}-1}{h-\log(1+h)}$$ The first factor te ds to $1$ so the desired limit is equal to the limit of the following expression $$\frac{\exp(h\log(1+h))-1}{h\log(1+h)}\cdot\frac{\log(1+h)}{h}\cdot\frac{h^{2}}{h-\log(1+h)}$$ All factors except the last tend to $1$ and the last factor tends to $2$ using Taylor series or L'Hospital's Rule. So the desired limit is $2$.